# To use @BeforeMethod in TestNG, must public WebDriver driver; public String baseUrl; be first created?

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

To use @BeforeMethod in TestNG, must this be first created?

```
public WebDriver driver;    
public String baseUrl;
```

This worked:

```
public class TestClass {
  public WebDriver driver;
  public String baseUrl;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void Homepage() {
  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  baseUrl = "http://www.indeed.co.uk";
}
```

The below refused to work as the driver did not get passed from @BeforeMethod to @Test.

```
public class TestClass {
  @BeforeMethod
  public void home() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }

  @Test
  public void Setup() {
    driver.get("http://www.indeed.co.uk");`
  }
}
```

The driver in @BeforeMethod has no red squiggly line. The one in @ test does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we need to declare driver object globally or class level. like below

```
 public class TestClass {

 public WebDriver driver; 

 //...... }
```

if we declare driver object inside any method may be home() here, then it becomes local object to home only and does not have visibility or accessibility in all methods in class. please refer [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm) for variables

//** updating the answer on URL

in below @Test we are providing the URL directly. So need of public String baseUrl variable

```
 @Test
 public void Setup() {

driver.get("http://www.indeed.co.uk");`
}
```

If you want to create variable and willing to use that variable in @Test then  create baseUrl as global and you can assign value directly, like below

```
public class TestClass {

public String baseUrl="http://www.indeed.co.uk";

//use this baseUrl in @test like below
@Test
public void Setup() {

driver.get(baseUrl);`
}
```

Also we can create baseUrl as globally and can assign value in BeforeTest like below

```
public class TestClass {

public WebDriver driver; public String baseUrl;

@BeforeMethod
public void Homepage() {

driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "http://www.indeed.co.uk";

}

// as we declared baseUrl globally and assigned value in beforetest, so we use this variable in @tests now

 @Test
public void Setup() {

driver.get(baseUrl);`
} 
}
```

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: This makes sense Murali; however, what of                                            public String baseUrl                                                                                                  Must that also be declared at class level?

Comment: Same for URL also, if you want to use baseUrl in all methods in class then declare as global variable. If you are willing to pass URL directly in get like this driver.get("http://www.indeed.co.uk");` then no need to create baseURL variable also. i hope you got it.

Comment: Our messages crossed. For clarity, you are saying its possible to pass URL directly as local object in @Test with driver.get(""); without creating baseURL variable at class level?

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386805/webdriver-can-login-in-chrome-not-in-firefox-unable-to-find-owning-document?noredirect=1#comment68046048_40386805